# Radio buttons in different parts of the page

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I need to place radio button controls with ICEFaces in different parts of my page, according to a layout specification I must meet.

`SelectOneRadio` control allows me to instantiate several radio buttons **in the same container**, but I need to place just two radio buttons inside certain table cells, and I then need some controls to be activated or not according to which radio button is selected.

With plain HTML, I obviously need to place the two `<input`s wherever I need and give them the same name.

How can I achieve the same using ICEFaces so I can enable/disable controls according to the selection of a specific radio option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no utter idea what IceFaces provides, but Tomahawk has a [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) control which supports an extra `layout` attribute with value of `spread` which allows you to place the individual radio buttons everywhere you want in the markup using [`<t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_radio.html).

E.g.

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.foos}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>
...
<t:radio for="foo" index="0" />
...
<t:radio for="foo" index="1" />
...
<t:radio for="foo" index="2" />
...
```

---

**Update** as turns out, IceFaces has cloned this Tomahawk-invented feature [since version 1.7](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-751). So just substitute `t:` with `ice:` in above example and it'll work as good.

Comment: ICEFaces provides it too!! :)