# Custom selectItems

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-2

i want to customize **selectItems** 
to display an image conditionally beside each checkbox
so first i tried to display the image for all checkboxes
but it gets displayed only once, here's what i tried:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{myBean.checkboxesArry}" layout="pageDirection">

              <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.mapOfCheckBoxes}" var="entry">                            
                <label>           
                <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/myImage.bmp"/>            
                <b>#{entry.value}</b>           
                </label>
              </f:selectItems>

            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

please advise how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest UI compnents in `<f:selectItems>` that way. I however see that you're using ICEfaces, you should then be able to use `<ice:selectManyCheckbox layout="spread">` in combination with `<ice:checkbox>` instead.

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox id="foo" value="#{myBean.checkboxesArry}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.mapOfCheckBoxes}" />
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>

<c:forEach items="#{myBean.mapOfCheckBoxes}" var="entry" varStatus="loop">
    <ice:checkbox for="foo" index="#{loop.index}" />
    <ice:graphicImage url="/resources/images/myImage.bmp" />
    <b>#{entry.value}</b>
</c:forEach>
```

*(untested as I don't use ICEfaces, but the above construct works for Tomahawk, from which ICEfaces has basically copied the implementation; you can also use `<ui:repeat>` but it only supports `Map` since JSF 2.1)*

#### See also:

- [Radio buttons in different parts of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218019/radio-buttons-in-different-parts-of-the-page)

Comment: when i tried that no checkboxes appears  at all, do i have to include form name before the id ?

Comment: Just to test, what if you specify the checkboxes individually with a fixed ID? Like so `<ice:checkbox for="foo" index="0" />` etc. If that works, then try `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<c:forEach>`, only with a `List` instead of `Map` if you aren't on JSF 2.1 yet.

Comment: fixed id works fine, but ui:repeat doesn't work either, strange! any ideas ?

Comment: well, after debugging i found that i was doing something wrong, i was initializing the map in the prerenderView method while the map is getting accessed by the foreach before that phase, don't fully understand why, but it works fine now.

Comment: but is there's a way to make the label of the checkbox dynamic based on a condition to make the label bold or not ?

Comment: Just use `<h:outputText styleClass="#{someCondition ? 'bold' : ''}">`.

Comment: As to the map initializing, the `<c:forEach>` is a view build time tag, not a view render time tag like `<ui:repeat>`. So you need to initialize in (post)constructor instead, or to replace it by `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: one more question, i wanted to add after the checkbox a conditional image, and conditional style for the label, what the above code generates is the `image > bold text > checkbox > checkbox text`, while i though that this will generate only: `image > bold text > checkbox` please advise how to accomplish that

Comment: Remove the labels from `<f:selectItems>` value.

Comment: Just don't supply item labels. E.g. `itemLabel=""`.

Comment: well, i tried the following but still displaying the label after the checkbox: `<f:selectItems value="#{messageBean.toSendCheckBoxes}" itemLabel=""/>`

Comment: tried the following, but doesn't work too: `<f:selectItems value="#{messageBean.toSendCheckBoxes}"  var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.value}" itemLabel=""/>`

Comment: No? Sorry, then I don't know it. Ask a new question. It's perhaps related to ICEfaces.

Comment: another question is asked, but any ideas how to display the list in the above code in vertical not horizontal i mean to be equivalent to pageDirection layout ?

Comment: Wrap them in `<div style="float:left;">`.