# How to split radio button but keep grouping

Tags: css, jsf, radio-button, seam

Im new to JSF (and Seam, JBOSS, and what not) and I got this task to add a text between the first radio button and the second one, as in the picture (the red text):

[image]

This really puzzles me. Is this achievable? Today it just spits out the radio buttons (from a List<>):

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="foobarAlternativRadio" value="#{foobarController.valdFoobarAlternativ}" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="radio" style="margin: 0" tabindex="#{nextTabIndex}" disabled="#{foobarController.visaAnnan}">
    <s:selectItems value="#{foobarController.foobarAlternativ}" var="alternativ" label="#{alternativ.itemLabel()}"/>
    <s:convertEnum />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

It would be easy to solve with JavaScript, but it's not an option since it has to work without JS.

My questions:

- Can this be done?

if so:

- What approach should I have / where to start? (can I write some kind of a own render structure?)

Addtional info: I have to come up with a solution that works with IE6 and newer web browsers without the use of JS.

*Edit: Is CSS a way to solve this in some way?*

Comment: I think what you need is quite constrained by the existing framework, I also ever tried to achieve similar effect by applying a4j:repeat or c:foreach, but didn't work out. You can also refer to another discuss thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529612/how-display-something-near-hselectoneradio-item)

Comment: Use `<t:selectOneRadio layout="spread">`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with CSS. Try something like this:

```
.radio:first-child:after {
    content: "Your content";
    color: #FF000;
}
```

Comment: CSS content is not supported by IE 6 or 7 :-/ Thanks for the tips tho!